# Find matching index based on multiple files and print

Tags: indexing, awk, matching

I have 3 files as below, all 3 files have same number of col and row (more than hundreds). What I want is: find the col/row if the number in both File1 and File2 falling in a specific range, then keep the number in File3 with same index and sign "0" to  other numbers. eg: from File1 and File2, only numbers at col2/row2 can meet the standard (0<88<100, 0<6<10), then keep the number 8 from File3 and assign "0" to all other numbers. Is it possible to use awk to do that? Or python? Thank you.

File1:

```
-10 -10 9 
-20 88 106 
-30 300 120
```

File2:

```
-6 0 -7
-5 6 1
-2 18 32
```

File3:

```
4 3 5 
6 8 8
10 23 14
```

output

```
0 0 0
0 8 0
0 0 0
```

Comment: Good question, also try to add more clear conditions(in this case ranges) + your effort to solve the issue, as we all are here to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following `awk` will help here.

```
awk '
FNR==1                 { count++             }  ##Checking condition if FNR==1 then increment variable count with 1 each time.
count==1               {                        ##Checking condition if count is either 1 or 2 if yes then do following.
   for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)  {                        ##Starting a usual for loop from variable value 1 to till value of NF here and doing following.
     if($i>0 && $i<100){ a[FNR,i]++          }  ##Checking condition if a field value is greater than 0 and lesser than 100 then increment 1 count for array a whose index is line_number and column_number here. So this will have the record of which ever line whichever column has values in range and if count is 2 then we should print it.
}}
count==2               {
   for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)  {
     if($i>0 && $i<10) { a[FNR,i]++          }
}}
count==3               {                        ##Checking condition if variable count is 3 here then do following.
   for(j=1;j<=NF;j++)  { $j=a[FNR,j]==2?$j:0 }; ##Starting a for loop here from 1 to till NF value and checking condition if array a with index of line_number and column_number is 2(means both File1 and File2 have same ranges) then keep its same value else make it 0 as per OP request.
   print                                     }  ##Printing the current line edited/non-edited value here.
' File1 File2 File3                             ##Mentioning all Input_file(s) here.
```

Output will be as follows.

```
0 0 0
0 8 0
0 0 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I understand $i>0 && $i<100 is for File1, but I am not sure where you add the range requirement for File2 (0<num<10)? Also would you please add more detailed explanation?

Comment: thank you for taking time to provide the explanation! But the range requirement for File2 ( $i>0 && $i<10) is different than File1 ($i>0 && $i<100), how to deal with that?

Comment: @kelly, ok cool changed code now, check and let me know if All is Well??

Answer (score 1):

You have a great `awk` answer.

Here is how you might do this in Python with numpy.

First, read the files:

```
import numpy as np
arrays=[]
for fn in ('file1', 'file2', 'file3'):
    with open(fn) as f:
        arrays.append(np.array([line.split() for line in f],dtype=float))
```

Then create a mask matrix to filter for the desired conditions:

```
mask=(arrays[0]>0) & (arrays[0]<100) & (arrays[1]>0) & (arrays[1]<10)
```

Then multiply the third array (`arrays[2]` is the third file) by the mask:

```
>>> arrays[2] * mask.astype(float)
[[0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 8. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]]
```